# When would you want to use disable_ddl_transaction in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, migration, rails-activerecord

My understanding is that all migrations are wrapped in a transaction, meaning, if a change for 1 row, like adding null: false, in a table fails, every other row will fail. When would you not want this to happen with `disable_ddl_transaction`?

Answer (score 33):

All migrations are wrapped in transaction by default so that they can be rolled back when they are failed.

You need to use `disable_ddl_transaction` when you want to do something that can not excute inside a transaction. You can check `Transactional Migrations` section of [Migration document](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) for example.

Comment: One example that comes to mind is when adding a custom/user-defined Enum in PGSQL. They cant be defined in a transaction, so adding them via a Rails migration requires `disable_ddl_transaction!` called when the class is loaded, before its `#up` method is evoked.

Answer (score 9):

When you want to add an index on a large table using a concurrent (algorithm) approach, which prevents the table from getting locked while the index is being added, you need to `disable_ddl_transaction` since the concurrent approach can't be executed inside the transaction. Please find more details [here](https://jetrockets.com/blog/kbz5cbkded-how-to-add-index-to-a-large-working-app-on-rails).